# How to Update CollectionView Model with Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

I am trying to intitialize my Collection View Model which holds a list of [Users] with a firebase snap that holds data.

Here is the Collection View Model code:

```
typealias JSON = [String:Any]

    class HomeDataSource: Datasource {
        var users: [User]
        init?(with snapshot:DataSnapshot) {
            var users = [User]()
            guard let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String: [String:Any]] else {return nil}

            for snap in snapDict {
                guard let user = User(dict: snap.value) else {continue}
                users.append(user)
            }

            self.users = users
        }
    }
```

User Model:

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    let username: String

    init?(dict: JSON) {
        guard let name = dict["name"] as? String,
                let email = dict["email"] as? String
        else {return nil}
        self.name = name
        self.username = email
    }
}
```

Firebase Snap:

```
Snap (users) {
    8CVeHMNHI6hZAWj1zhGHEjPwYYz1 =     {
        email = "Silviu@isidors.sjsj";
        name = Bshdjdj;
    };
    9CuqgR4Es7TOPPJQEpSnQXlfYnm1 =     {
        email = "Test@silviu.com";
        name = "Test@silviu.com";
    };
    DBqGWlpdJKME570euqUz2rqI5Z83 =     {
        email = "Test@test.test";
        name = Test;
   };
}
```

Fetch Function:

```
func fetchUser() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let user = User(dict: snapshot.value as! JSON)
        self.users.append(user!)
        print(self.users)
        let new = HomeDataSource(with: snapshot)
        print(new)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.datasource = new
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Right now, I am getting an array of Users from Firebase, however my collection view won't update.

My question is how should I update my Collection View Model and Fetching Function so it can fetch data from Firebase and Populate the Collection View Correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the node I was targeting. Removed "`child("users")`" form fetching function and targeted the whole users node with uids. Then I was looping the snapshot.value while I casted it in [String:[String:Any]], because each `snapshot.value`looked like this `(key: "vijwUkzAlbgcqjAammfy0JuVMB33", value: ["name": Silviu, "email": Office@isidors.com])` Finally, I updated the HomeDataShource Class like this:

```
class HomeDataSource: Datasource {

var users: [User]

init(with snapshot:DataSnapshot) {
    var users = [User]()

    let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Any]]

    for snap in snapDict! {
        guard let user = User(snap: snap.value) else {continue}
        users.append(user)
    }
    self.users = users
}
```